# About "linear" Yang-Mills theories

Tags: yang-mills

Is it sensible to say about "linear" YM theories with tiny YM fields, thus removing the nonlinear YM self-interaction terms from the Lagrangian which therefore only contains the linear YM field interaction with matter?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26994/2451